# Update ApexClass/ApexTrigger/ApexPages code using DML Not Allowed

Tags: soql, community

I am trying very simple thing I just want to update any ApexClass, Apex Trigger, or Apex Pages code using DML operation something like.

```
ApexClass mApexClass =[Select body, version from ApexClass where name =: myClass]
mApexClass.body =  myUpdatedCodeText;
update mApexClass;
```

but I am not able to perform any DML operation on ApexClass/ApexTrigger/ApexPages. I look similar Question at this link [DML not allowed on ApexClass](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32527/dml-not-allowed-on-apexclass)
but that is not clear to me. I am new to salesforce so I don't know much about adding Tooling API, the Metadata API, or Apex API. All I want is to update the code of ApexClass or Trigger or Page from my ApexClass.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend the following resources to learn the Salesforce technical environment: [Force.com Workbook](
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/workshops_intro.htm), [Apex Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_workbook.htm) and [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/).

Answer (score 3):

The executing environment in a Salesforce org - including the Apex classes - is assumed by the platform design to not be changing within individual requests (transactions) in normal Apex code. So while information about the classes can be queried, changing those classes is explicitly blocked.

The normal way to update Apex code and pages etc is through the web-based setup UI or change sets or the development tools (such as the Force.com IDE or MavensMate) or through the Ant-based [Force.com Migration Tool](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf) that can be used for continuous integration or through creating and deploying managed packages.

However, there are APIs - originally designed to allow development tools to  modify the environment - that can also be called from Apex code. Bear in mind that using these APIs as a routine part of your app's execution is somewhat outside of what the platform is designed to do. Only consider it if you have a strong reason to do so and can't make your app work otherwise.

The API's involve web service calls. You are making a web service call from the org back to the same org. You will not see the changes you make in the current request (transaction) but will in requests you make after.

The usual place to start is the [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) project on Github. That includes many links that you should review carefully. Essentially it is the result of turning one of the web service APIs - the [Metadata API](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_meta.pdf) - into Apex code so that it can be conveniently called from Apex code.

The [Tooling API](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_tooling.pdf) is a newer API that somewhat overlaps with the Metadata API. There is a similar Github project for that too [Apex Tooling API - SOAP Edition](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi). I can't advise which is better to use; I have only used the Metadata API and generally I think the Metadata API has been used more from Apex.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot perform **DML** directly on executable code or configurable logic. It requires Tooling API or Metdata API.

Here is the direction, look at the following URL: [Force.com Tooling API : intmist.wordpress.com](https://intmist.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/force-com-tooling-api-create-apex-class-apex-trigger-dynamically-and-updatedelete-apex-trigger-apex-class-using-tooling-api-with-rest-api/)

It has provided basic way of creating ApexClass, Trigger and other supported items using Tooling API.

**Sample code from the link:**

> ```
>     public void createApexClass()
>     {
>         // create a Http request with post method
>         HttpRequest req = createHttpRequest(endpoint+'/ApexClass','POST');
>         req.setBody( '{"Name":"NewApexClass1","Body":"public class NewApexClass1 {}"}');
>         // send request and receive response
>         String response = getResponse(req);
>         // These two lines have no role in creating apex class. So they can be ignored for now.
>         Map<String,Object> rmp = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeuntyped(response);
>         oid = (String)rmp.get('id}
>     }
> ```

Comment: thanks Thanks a lottt :) for the link this is really very helpful to me....